# Incompatibility between titlesec and sectsty

Tags: titlesec, sectsty

I am used to use the package `titlesec` to change the font of my sections.
And now I want all my sections to be in blue, I find an easy way to do it with the `sectsty` package.
This is pretty useful because I don't have to change all type individually, but all in one.
Unfortunately, there is an incompatibility with `titlesec` as you can see on the MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\scshape\bfseries} 
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\scshape\bfseries} 

\allsectionsfont{\color{blue}{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First section}

blabla

\section{Second section} \subsection{Subsection}

blabla

\end{document}
```

The section with `\titleformat*` are not in blue, and if the `\usepackage{titlesec}` is before `\usepackage{sectsty}`, all the sections are in blue, but I lost the change in the font.

It looks normal, the last package called defines the style, but how can I do both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing the fonts for each section level, you need to add the `\color` command to those changes using `sectsty`. But there is no bold small caps font in Latin Modern, so you need to choose between bold and small caps.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\color{blue}}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\color{blue}} 
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\large\scshape\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
blabla
\section{Second section} 
\subsection{Subsection}
\section*{Unnumbered section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: True, but I have to do that for all the section/chapter... I wanted to do it at once.
Also does it work for the table of contents? With the command `\allsectionsfont{\color{blue}{}}` it does, but can I do it with `titlesec`?

Comment: I forgot to tag you, so I don't if you will see my new question!

Comment: @antoine I've changed to a `sectsty` solution, which is a bit simpler.  But since you're making changes to the fontsize for the different sections you need to add the colour to each.